# How can I remove strange gap between image and border on html page

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

in the articles section of a html page im working on there is a small gap between the images and the border.

Here is the HTML

```
 <article>
     <section class="image">
         <a href=""><img src="images/Thumbnail.gif" height="150" width="150" alt=""/></a>
     </section>
     <aside class="textBox">
         <h3>Project</h3>
         <p>description</p>
     </aside>
 </article>
```

And here is the CSS (there is some redundant parts i'm removing them at the moment)

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #64748B;
  padding: 4em;
  color: #000;
  background-image: url("images/background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
H1 {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 40pt;
}
.NavUl {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px outset;
  border-color: #22222B
}
.textBox {
  height: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
header {
  background-color: #090B16;
  width: 100%;
  border: 6px outset #22222B;
}
article {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #090B16;
  border: 6px outset #22222B;
  padding: 0
}
a:link, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.logo {
  padding: 1em;
}
p {
  font-size: 12pt;
}
.image {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 6px inset #7079B1
}
.post {
  width: 100%;
    
}
```

I don't know if this makes a difference but im using adobe dream weaver (which I hate, VSC superiority)

Ive tried messing with the padding and margins as well as the height, alas none of these things has made a difference.

Comment: Set the size of your images with CSS, not HTML

Comment: Try `display: block` on the image, to remove the default space at the bottom that aligns it with text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added `height:150px` to your `.image` CSS, it seems to have removed the space at the bottom.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #64748B;
  padding: 4em;
  color: #000;
  background-image: url("images/background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
H1 {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 40pt;
}
.NavUl {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px outset;
  border-color: #22222B
}
.textBox {
  height: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
header {
  background-color: #090B16;
  width: 100%;
  border: 6px outset #22222B;
}
article {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #090B16;
  border: 6px outset #22222B;
  padding: 0
}
a:link, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.logo {
  padding: 1em;
}
p {
  font-size: 12pt;
}
.image {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 6px inset #7079B1
}
.post {
  width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
 <article>
     <section class="image">
         <a href=""><img src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png" height="150" width="150" alt=""/></a>
     </section>
     <aside class="textBox">
         <h3>Project</h3>
         <p>description</p>
     </aside>
 </article>
```

Answer (score -1):

img default display is inline and its default vertical-align I think is baseline. I think it causes this behavier. you also can set its vertical-align top or bottom or middle to omit this gap.

add this css:

```
.image img {
  display:block
}
```

or:

```
.image img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

or:

```
.image img {
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

or:

```
.image img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.